# How to copy a complete DOM Form into a textfield and send it with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, copy, clone

I have a List with many ads. Every ad has the the same class like the following example:

```
<div class="ad1-wpr">...some code...</div>
<div class="ad1-wpr">...some code...</div>
<div class="ad1-wpr">...some code...</div>
and so on...
```

All div`s are the same, only the img, title, wag and ver2 are different:

```
<div class="ad1-wpr">
 <img>link to img</img>
 <div class="title">Title</div>
 <select name="wag">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
 </select>
 <input name="res" id="ver2" value="">
 <button type="button" id="selad" class="button">Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Now, when the button selad is clicked, i need the ad DOM from the nearest ad with the selected and filled data from user, copy it to a textfield named "finish-text" and send the form.

My problem is when i clone the DOM i haven´t the select and filled data inside and in the "finish-text" are no text to send it:

```
$(function(){
$('#selad').click(function() {

    var $text = $('.ad1-wpr').clone();
    $('.finish-text').html($text);

});});
```

Update: Now i have the solution to extract the selectbox and input data (Thanks to @AthMav):

```
    myFunc = function(el){

  var parent = $(el).parent();
  var selectValue = parent.find("select").val();
  var inputValue = parent.find("input").val();

  $(".finish-text").val(selectValue + ", " + inputValue);


}
```

How can i extract the DOM from "ad1-wpr" and paste it in the "finish-text" field with the values from above? Thanks!

Comment: can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: @AthMav - post edited

Answer (score 0):

```js
myFunc = function(el){

  var parent = $(el).parent();
  var selectValue = parent.find("select").val()
        
  $(".finish-text").val(selectValue);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ad1-wpr">
  <select name="wag">
    <option value="first">first</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick=myFunc(this)>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Might be something like this you are after? Might be wise to properly bind the click event of the button instead of onclick in the markup though.